# Single word for a thing being described in a legend (i.e., a table such as on a map)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a document where I use legends to describe abbreviations, short column names, units... generally things for which I don't have enough place in the main text to explain / elaborate.

These legend are formatted as a table, second column having the title "description", however I can't find a good title for the first column (abbreviations / words / expressions being described / explained).

What should be a good word here?

Comment: Why not just "Item"? Or "symbol"?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLeach! I didn't yet thought of it. That surely would make sense, however I'd like to get something with the meaning that this "item" will be described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a [glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary).

Usually the column headers are *term* and *definition.* However, a lot of glossaries don't have any table column header. Just name the annex *glossary* and put the terms left and the definitions right.